# Access virtuemart product data externally

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Is there a quick fire method of accessing all the data for a product from an external file by using its sku?

I have looked at [How can I get prodcut data of a VirtueMart 2 product in an external file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204394/how-can-i-get-prodcut-data-of-a-virtuemart-2-product-in-an-external-file)

and tried to replace the Product ID with my desired id but to no avail:

```
if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');
VmConfig::loadConfig();
if (!class_exists( 'VmModel' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'vmmodel.php');

$productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
$product = $productModel->getProduct(Product_ID);
```

In short terms, I'm looking for a way to access product data.

Comment: Its working fine. Just do a var_dump($product) and check data.

Comment: Yes, it is with product id. But how can I make it work with product sku? So I  can use the sku as the lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product sku may not be unique. so I have found a solution that works for me. Hope this helps you. This is the full code that you need to call product by sku externally.

```
<?php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', 'C:\Server\www\joomla' );//you will have diff location for your site

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

function getproductBySKU($sku){
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $db->setQuery(true);
  $db->setQuery("SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM #__virtuemart_products WHERE product_sku= $sku");
  $productids = $db->loadAssocList();
  return $productids;
}

function getProduct($id)
{
    if (!class_exists('VmConfig')) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart' . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'config.php');
    VmConfig::loadConfig();
    if (!class_exists('VmModel')) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart' . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'vmmodel.php');

    $productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
    $product = $productModel->getProduct($id);
    return $product;
}

$products = getproductBySKU(1);//In this example SKU is 1 having 2 products
var_dump($products);//Gives the product id's in the SKU
foreach($products as $product){
    var_dump(getProduct($product));
}
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks! I had one small issue - my SKUs were Strings and therefore I had to modify the SQL slightly, to `'$sku'`

Comment: @ak1652 is it working for after you made those changes?